# How can we check that what font the browser is using?

Tags: meta-tags

I have used font-family in css as simsun. But there is no font in my system called simsun but I have to know what the font is taken by a browser to display.

Comment: Please indicate which browser.  Many browsers have good debugging functions for this sort of thing, but they are all different.

Answer (score 0):

Try cutting and pasting into word (or another word processor), and then look at what font word is using.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on browser.  But you can set list of fonts in your css-file:

```
font-family:'Lucida Grande','Verdana',sans-serif;
```

Comment: i am specifying some chinese fonts but i dont how it look like.its not coming same in all machine . i mean its showing different in other machines.