# How to find the exact font used by the browser

Tags: fonts, metatag

I have written a 2 texts one is in english and one is Chinese language. i have kept font-family as Arial and simhei for both the text. actually what i need to know is when i check using font finder tool it should show which font is exactly rendering in browser. but when i check with the tool its showing arial for both. when i remove the simhei font from my machine then its not showing font at all. so my think is chinese font is using simhei and english is using arial.so i need to know exact font used by the browser. Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can we check that what font the browser is using?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4223276/how-can-we-check-that-what-font-the-browser-is-using)

Answer (score 1):

[This Firefox extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/4415/) might be interesting.

Comment: Thanks,this looks great, but what i wanted to know exactly is---> I have written a 2 texts one is in english and one is Chinese language. i have kept font-family as Arial and simhei for both the text. actually what i need to know is when i check using font finder tool it should show which font is exactly rendering in browser. but when i check with the tool its showing arial for both. when i remove the simhei font from my machine then its not showing font at all. so my think is chinese font is using simhei and english is using arial.so i need to know exact font used by the browser. Thanks